# Выпуклый многоугольник

Tags: c++, g++

Многоугольник – замкнутая ломаная.
Простым называется многоугольник без самопересечений, самокасаний.
Выпуклым называется многоугольник, ограничивающий выпуклую область.
Выпуклой называется область A, обладающая свойством P, Q∈A⇒[P,Q]⊆A.

*Формат ввода*
В первой строке одно число
N (3≤N≤100000). Далее в N строках по паре целых чисел — координаты очередной вершины простого многоугольника в порядке обхода по или против часовой стрелки.

*Формат вывода*
Одна строка «YES», если приведённый многоугольник является выпуклым, и «NO» в противном случае.

*Пример*

*Ввод*:

```
3
0 0
0 1
1 0
```

*Вывод*:

```
YES
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как это делать?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

struct Point {
    int x, y;
    Point() {}
    Point(int x, int y) :x(x), y(y) {}
};

Point operator -(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    return Point(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y);
}

//dotProduct
int dP(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    return a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y;
}

//crossProduct
int cP(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    return a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x;
}

bool operator ==(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    return a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y;
}

double len(const Point& a) {
    return hypot(a.x, a.y);
}

double angle(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    return atan2(cP(a, b), dP(a, b));
}

bool PointOnSegment(const Point& a, const Point& b, const Point& p) {
    if (p == a || p == b) return true;
    return cP(a - p, b - p) == 0 && dP(a - p, b - p) < 0;
}

istream& operator >>(istream& in, Point& p) {
    in >> p.x >> p.y;
    return in;
}

bool ccw(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
    float s = cP(c - a, c - b) / 2.0;
    if (s < 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}

bool is_convex(vector<Point>& p) {
    int l, i, r;
    int n = p.size();
    bool isccw = ccw(p[n - 1], p[0], p[1]);
    for (i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        l = (i - 1 + n) % n;
        r = (i + 1) % n;
        if (ccw(p[l], p[i], p[r]) != isccw)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}


int main() {
    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); cin.tie(0); cout.tie(0);

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<Point> points;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int x, y;
        cin >> x >> y;
        points.push_back(Point(x, y));
    }

    cout << (is_convex(points) ? "YES" : "NO");

    return 0;
}
```

В тестирующей системе выдает ошибку WA на 28 тесте. (неправильный ответ на 28-ом тесте). Подскажите пожалуйста, как исправить.

Comment: а ошибка то в чем именно заключается не говорится?

Comment: нет, просто говорится, что ответ неправильный

Comment: Это нетривиальная задача. Даже банальное определение того,  находится ли точка внутри полигона. Если задачи сделать самому не стоит, то есть такая либка, которая называется `Boost.Geometry`.

Comment: Задачу нужно решить самостоятельно, ведь я ее сдаю в тестирующую систему

Comment: Тогда советую найти такую книжку `Компьютерная геометрия и алгоритмы машинной графики (Никулин) (2003)` =)

Comment: Как идея - идти по(против) часовой стрелки и сравнивать направление на следующую точку и на следующую за ней - и если вдруг направление оказывается левее (правее), чем на следующую - то многоугольник не выпуклый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

выпуклую оболочку можно найти с помощью алгоритма Грэхема. В вашем случае если после построения выпуклой оболочки останутся лишние точки то из ваших точек нельзя построить выпуклую оболочку.

> Алгоритм. Найдём самую левую и самую правую точки A и B (если таких
> точек несколько, то возьмём самую нижнюю среди левых, и самую верхнюю
> среди правых). Понятно, что и A, и B обязательно попадут в выпуклую
> оболочку. Далее, проведём через них прямую AB, разделив множество всех
> точек на верхнее и нижнее подмножества S1 и S2 (точки, лежащие на
> прямой, можно отнести к любому множеству - они всё равно не войдут в
> оболочку). Точки A и B отнесём к обоим множествам. Теперь построим для
> S1 верхнюю оболочку, а для S2 - нижнюю оболочку, и объединим их,
> получив ответ. Чтобы получить, скажем, верхнюю оболочку, нужно
> отсортировать все точки по абсциссе, затем пройтись по всем точкам,
> рассматривая на каждом шаге кроме самой точки две предыдущие точки,
> вошедшие в оболочку. Если текущая тройка точек образует не правый
> поворот (что легко проверить с помощью Ориентированной площади), то
> ближайшего соседа нужно удалить из оболочки. В конце концов, останутся
> только точки, входящие в выпуклую оболочку.
>
> Итак, алгоритм заключается в сортировке всех точек по абсциссе и двух
> (в худшем случае) обходах всех точек, т.е. требуемая асимптотика O (N
> log N) достигнута.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Point
{
  double x, y;
};

bool cmp(Point a, Point b)
{
  return a.x < b.x || a.x == b.x && a.y < b.y;
}

bool cw(Point a, Point b, Point c)
{
  return a.x * (b.y - c.y) + b.x * (c.y - a.y) + c.x * (a.y - b.y) < 0;
}

bool ccw(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
  return a.x * (b.y - c.y) + b.x * (c.y - a.y) + c.x * (a.y - b.y) > 0;
}

void convex_hull(std::vector<Point>& a)
{
  if (a.size() == 1) {
    return;
  }

  std::sort(a.begin(), a.end(), &cmp);
  Point p1 = a[0], p2 = a.back();
  std::vector<Point> up, down;
  up.push_back(p1);
  down.push_back(p1);

  for (size_t i = 1; i < a.size(); ++i) {
    if (i == a.size() - 1 || cw(p1, a[i], p2)) {
      while (up.size() >= 2 && !cw(up[up.size() - 2], up[up.size() - 1], a[i])) {
        up.pop_back();
      }
      up.push_back(a[i]);
    }
    if (i == a.size() - 1 || ccw(p1, a[i], p2)) {
      while (down.size() >= 2 && !ccw(down[down.size() - 2], down[down.size() - 1], a[i])) {
        down.pop_back();
      }
      down.push_back(a[i]);
    }
  }

  a.clear();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < up.size(); ++i) {
    a.push_back(up[i]);
  }
  for (size_t i = down.size() - 2; i > 0; --i) {
    a.push_back(down[i]);
  }
}
```

материал взят с сайта [e-maxx.ru](https://e-maxx.ru/algo/convex_hull_graham)

Comment: Это способ рабочий. Первое: если у многоугольника три вершины на одной прямой, то Грехэм не включит среднюю точку из этой тройки. При этом многоугольник остаётся выпуклым множеством. Нужно доработать. Второе - медленно: Грехэм `NlogN`, а проверить выпуклость можно за  `N`.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy спасибо, вы абсолютно правы

Answer (score 3):

Не нужно строить выпуклую оболочку чтобы проверить что простой многоугольник является выпуклым. Вы упустили один-единственный случай: три точки могут оказаться на одной прямой. В этом случае вы не можете полагаться на

```
bool isccw = ccw(p[n - 1], p[0], p[1]);
```

Исправить можно просто: отыщите самую нижнюю вершину, если их несколько, то из них выберите самую левую. `isccw` нужно считать на этой тройке.

И в цикле тоже надо учитывать что три или более точек могут лежать на одной прямой. Функцию `ccw` надо будет переделать так чтобы она могла возвращать три состояния.

Альтернативное решение - посчитать `ccw` на всех тройках вершин и убедится что она не возвращает и "лево" и "право". Так, наверно, проще:

```
// g++ -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra is_convex.cpp

#include <bits/stdc++.h>

struct Point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int read_int() {
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    return i;
}

Point read_point() {
    int x = read_int();
    int y = read_int();
    return {x, y};
}

Point operator -(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    return {a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y};
}

int cross(const Point& a, const Point& b) {
    return a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x;
}

int area2(const Point& a, const Point& b, const Point& c) {
    return cross(c - a, c - b);
}

class Clock {
public:
    Clock(const Point& p1, const Point& p2) : p1(p1), p2(p2), has_ccw(false), has_cw(false) {}
    bool update(const Point& p3) {
        int a = area2(p1, p2, p3);
        has_ccw = has_ccw || a < 0;
        has_cw = has_cw || a > 0;
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = p3;
        return has_ccw && has_cw;
    }
private:
    Point p1;
    Point p2;
    bool has_ccw;
    bool has_cw;
};

bool is_convex() {
    const int n = read_int();
    const Point first = read_point();
    const Point second = read_point();

    Clock c(first, second);

    for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
        if (c.update(read_point())) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    if (c.update(first)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (c.update(second)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0); std::cin.tie(0); std::cout.tie(0);
    std::cout << (is_convex() ? "YES" : "NO");
    return 0;
}
```